# How to get sheet that is not first sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google scripting, so I apologize if this is a naive question. I do not know how to get a variable reference to a sheet within a spreadsheet that is not the first sheet.

In my spreadsheet, I have two sheets, `Agenda` and `Info`. Agenda is the first sheet(index 0) and Info is the second. I can get a reference to `Agenda`, but I cannot get a reference to Index. This is the code I have tried:

```
var info_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Info');
```

`info_sheet.getName()` always comes out being `Agenda`, though. What do I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get access to a specific sheet in a spreadsheet : by its name as you were showing in your code or by its index like in the second example below.

Just run this test to see the results on a spreadsheet with at least 2 sheets (I changed the sheet names to the 'standard default values in US locale' to make the test working for anyone, re-set it to your parameters if needed)

```
function testSheetNames(){
  var info_sheet_example1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var info_sheet_example2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  Logger.log('name method result = '+info_sheet_example1.getName());
  Logger.log('index method result = '+info_sheet_example2.getName());          
}
```

That said, your example should return the correct value, I'm not sure why it didn't in your tests.

Comment: You're right! Your example worked and so did mine. It turned out that I misspelled my variable by one letter. I'm sure we've all done that before...

Comment: And thank you for being patient with me and not putting a sarcastic answer about how I should have known. I really liked your answer and gave you an upvote for it as well.

Comment: Thanks, you're welcome... For sure I've done that kind of error too... so obvious that we just don't see it :-)